# How do I output to console when I click a button and why doesn't the text change when I click this button?

Tags: android

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView myText;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setText("Hello World");
        Button btn1 =  new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("Click here mofo");
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeText();

            }
        });

        setContentView(myText);
        setContentView(btn1);
    }


    public void changeText()
    {
        myText.setText("Changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: The text is changing. You can't see it because you aren't invalidating the view. In the `changeText()` method, add `invalidate();` after `myText.setText("Changed");`. This will tell the Activity to redraw itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can print text by using the android Logger: [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

```
Log.i(MY_TAG, "hello world");
```

You can see the output with logcat. If you are using eclipse you just have to open the logcat view and filter for your log tag.

You don't see a text changing because you can only have one content view within your activity.

```
setContentView(myText); // content view set to myText
setContentView(btn1); // content view set to btn1, myText is no longer visible
```

If you want to show `myText` and `btn1` you have to use a layout. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) can help you understanding layouts.

Comment: A Layout is obviously being used. Additionally, you do not need multiple layouts to change the visible properties of views. You simply need to redraw them. This can be done manually or by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Log.i or Lod.d can give output to LogCat

in my example button is defined in xml file.

```
public class StackActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText("Before");
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("YOUR TAG", "Hey You Just Clicked Me!");
                button1.setText("After");
            }
        });

    }
}
```